# Biblatex - remove extra spacing in citation range

Tags: biblatex, spacing

I am using a `biblatex-gost` package with a `gost-numeric` style. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{halanay,
    langid = {english},
    title = {Differential Equations Stability, Oscillations, Time Lags},
    author = {A. Halanay},
    location = {New York--London},
    publisher = {Acad. Press},
    year = {1968},
    pagetotal = {568},
}
@book{lakshmikantham,
    langid = {english},
    title = {Theory of Integro-Differential Equations},
    author = {V. Lakshmikantham and M. R. M. Rao},
    location = {London},
    publisher = {Gordon and Breach},
    year = {1995},
    pagetotal = {384},
}
@book{hartman,
    langid = {english},
    title = {Ordinary Differential Equations},
    author = {P. Hartman},
    location = {Philadelphia},
    publisher = {Society for Industrial and Applied Mathematics},
    year = {2002},
    pagetotal = {612},
}
\end{filecontents}       
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}       
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}         
\usepackage[english,ukrainian]{babel} 
\usepackage[backend=biber,bibencoding=utf8,maxbibnames=999,style=gost-numeric,language=auto,autolang=other]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\toggletrue{bbx:gostbibliography}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}

\begin{document}

This was investigated in \cite{halanay,lakshmikantham,hartman}. And that -- in \cite{hartman,halanay}.

\end{document}
```

But I get `[1   -3 ]` and `[1 ; 2 ]`, respectively.

[image]

How do I remove extra spacing in the citation range? I need to have simply `[1-3]` and `[1,2]` (comma instead of a semicolon, if possible).

Comment: Can't reproduce the issue with `pdflatex`

Comment: Strange, because I have this problem in `pdflatex`. Added a screenshot.

Comment: I can't reproduce this either, I get [1--3] and [1; 2] as expected (by me anyway). Since you are using an outdated version this could be due to a bug somewhere that got fixed. Does the same problem occur with `style=numeric`  instead of `style=gost-numeric`?

Comment: @moewe, after switching to `style=numeric` I get `[1 , 2 , 3 ]` and `[2 , 1 ]`. Extra spaces remain but the range dash is gone.

Comment: Change `language=auto` to `language=autobib`.

Comment: @moewe, wow that worked! Thank you! Can you please also help me change `[1; 2]` to `[1, 2]`? Or it involves redefining a lot of macros?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a fully updated system I get

[image]

as desired.

In the comments we established that if you change `language=auto` to

```
language=autobib
```

the spaces disappear. That shows that the problem lies with the language definitions on your system. The possible sources of problems are

- [Missing `%` to avoid spurious spaces](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453/35864) in `ukrainian.lbx`
- [Missing `%`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453/35864) in `\DefineBibliographyExtras{ukrainian}`
- [Missing `%`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453/35864) in `ukraineb.ldf`

Since we don't have your files, you will have to investigate that yourself. While it may be tempting to just say `language=autobib` and not investigate the source of the spurious space further that just treats the symptom, not the cause. You may end up with unwanted spaces in other situations where there is no easy way out, so do investigate a bit.

---

If you want to change the separator from a semicolon

> [1; 2]

into a comma you need

```
\renewcommand*{\multicitedelim}{\addcomma\space}
```

to get

> [1, 2]

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you! You're a TEX wizard *moewe*. I will definitely mention you during my thesis defend)

Comment: @user2513149 You will want to find out the real source of those spurious spaces, though. The `language=autobib` is just a workaround and theoretically you could get unwanted spaces in the bibliography as well. So you should check out the three possible sources of the space I mentioned above.